# Add new row in table using jquery in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

```
I'm want to add new row using jquery any one help me to solve my problem"
```

'''
    https://jsfiddle.net/dn6chabs/86/
     jsfiddle here want to add new row 
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there were quite a few issues with your code:

- If you check `console` by hitting `f12` you have this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $c is not defined` because of this line: `$("#field7").val($c);`
- I don't think it's necessary for the `add` and `remove` to be `<a>` tags, unless you want them specifically for styling, as it confuses the matter
- `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` this line doesn't really appear to do anything

Anyway, here's the corrected code!

- `$("#field7").val(c);`, this has been corrected
- The `add` and `remove` have been made `<span>` tags with custom styling to look like `<a>` tags
- The `onclick` event has been corrected in light of this
- The removal process has been fixed and is now `$('#table').children().eq($("#table").children().length - 1).not('tfoot').remove();`, whereby it **never** removes the subtotal / total line

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_to_table").on('click', function() {
    navObj = $("#table tbody:last").clone();
    $("#table").append(navObj);
  });
  $("#remove_from_table").on('click', function() {
    $('#table').children().eq($("#table").children().length - 1).not('tfoot').remove();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("field5").innerHTML;
  var b = document.getElementById("field6").InnerHTML;
  c = a * b;
  $("#field7").val(c);
});
```

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="add_to_table" class="link">Add</span>
<span id="remove_from_table" class="link">Remove</span>
<table id="table" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; border: 0px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr id="row">
      <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 400; color: #fff; font-size: 1.6em; background: #3989c6;">#</th>
      <th scope="row" class="text-left" style="white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 400; color: #fff; font-size: 1.6em; background: #3989c6;">DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th scope="row" class="text-right" style="white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 400; color: #fff; font-size: 1.6em; background: #3989c6;">UNITS</th>
      <th scope="row" class="text-right" style="white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 400; color: #fff; font-size: 1.6em; background: #3989c6;">PRICE</th>
      <th scope="row" class="text-right" style="white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 400; color: #fff; font-size: 1.6em; background: #3989c6;">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="field1" class="no" style="color: #fff; font-size: 1.6em; background: #3989c6;">01</td>
      <td id="field2" class="text-left" style="padding: 15px; background: #eee; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">
        <h3 id="field3">WebSite <em><strong>Consultansy</strong></em></h3>
        <em id="field4">Tasks related to meeting minutes AbC</em>
      </td>
      <td id="field5" class="qty" style="padding: 15px; background: #eee; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;">4</td>
      <td id="field6" class="unit" style="background: #ddd;">$100.00</td>
      <td id="field7" class="total" style="background: #3989c6; color: #fff;">$300.00</td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot style="display: table-footer-group; vertical-align: middle; border-color: inherit;">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: none;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="background: 0 0; border-bottom: none; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 1.2em; border-top: 1px solid #aaa;" colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
      <td style="background: 0 0; border-bottom: none; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 1.2em; border-top: 1px solid #aaa;">$300.00</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: none;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="background: 0 0; border-bottom: none; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 1.2em; border-top: 1px solid #aaa;" colspan="2"><em>TAX Deductions</em></td>
      <td style="background: 0 0; border-bottom: none; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 1.2em; border-top: 1px solid #aaa;">00.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: none;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="color: #3989c6; font-size: 1.4em; border-top: 1px solid #3989c6;" colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
      <td style="color: #3989c6; font-size: 1.4em; border-top: 1px solid #3989c6;">$300.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Check the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5btzk36v/)

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: @AsadSaeed Please mark as resolved if this fixed your issue

Comment: need to ask some more question 
i am implementing this on reactjs

Comment: i want to multiply unit column with price column and want to show their result in total column and when added new row its number should be increment number(e.g 1 then 2 and so on), and also want to sum total column values and show their result in subtotal and grand total rows

Comment: **Please mark my answer as accepted** & open a new question in Stack Overflow as this is a different topic.